# ksh on AIX - pwd in prompt does not update when changing folders

Tags: ksh, aix

I'm very new to AIX as well as ksh, but I currently have some downtime at work and am trying to configure my prompt to be both colored and show my current location.

At the moment, I get the correct path only once on login, afterwards it continues to show my user directory. Colors work fine. logname and hostname are correct.

```
PS1="$(echo "\033[35m`logname`\033[34m@\033[35m`hostname` \033[36m`pwd`\033[1;35m\n\>\033[0m") "
```

Can't show a screenshot, but sample output would look like this in any directory:

```
userid@hostname /home/look/a/subfolder
>
```

I tried a bunch of different versions but I either couldn't get it to show anything or all special characters appeared as written in .profile.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: Thanks to Stéphane, ESC+CTRL+V works, it's ksh88.
AIX 7.1

Comment: The substitutions, e.g. `\`pwd\`` are executed when you set the variable `PS1`, not when the shell displays the prompt.

Comment: Pressing Esc, followed by Ctrl+V may tell you the version. It's likely some versions of ksh88 since `${.sh.version}` is not supported.

Comment: There should be a letter after ksh88 (likely `i`) which gives the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
eval "$(print "
  fg_magenta='\033[35m' fg_blue='\033[34m' fg_cyan='\033[36m' 
  nl='\n' bold='\033[1m' sgr0='\033[m'")"

PS1="$fg_magenta$LOGNAME$fg_blue@$fg_magenta$(uname -n) $fg_cyan\$PWD$bold$fg_magenta$nl>$sgr0 "
```

That is, the things that don't change during a shell session, expand them upon assignment (unless they may contain `$`, `` ` ``, `\`, `!` characters, but for `$PWD` which changes any time you wan to store a literal `$PWD` into `$PS1` for that `$PWD` to be expanded upon prompt expansion¹

---

<sup>¹ Beware that if those expansions contain `!` characters, they will be expanded to the current history number, so strictly speaking that should be `${PWD//!/!!}` (`${param//pattern/replacement}` is a ksh93 operator though)</sup>

Comment: Yep, perfect colored prompt. Thank you as well! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've always used

```
PS1=$(hostname):'$PWD
$ '
```

Comment: Perfect. Works fine. Thank you!

Comment: Zum Wohl und Vergnügen.